How to Simulate Natural Falling Behavior for Stacked Shapes?
There is a thin, long rectangle placed slightly below a circle, and I let them fall simultaneously. When they hit the ground, they land perfectly aligned, one on top of the other.


In the real world, factors like air resistance (?), impact (?), and friction (?) make such a result almost miraculous.
What kind of approach can I take to make them naturally fall apart instead?
The following uses flame_forge2d, but since it's a wrapper for Box2D(Strictly speaking, it is a port of Box2D.), I believe approaches available in Box2D can be applied here as well.
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flame/extensions.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame_forge2d/flame_forge2d.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const GameWidget.controlled(gameFactory: Forge2DExample.new));
}

class Forge2DExample extends Forge2DGame {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();

    camera.viewport.add(FpsTextComponent());
    world.add(Ball());
    world.add(DominoBrick(Vector2.zero() + Vector2(0, 10)));
    world.addAll(createBoundaries());
  }

  List<Component> createBoundaries() {
    final visibleRect = camera.visibleWorldRect;
    final topLeft = visibleRect.topLeft.toVector2();
    final topRight = visibleRect.topRight.toVector2();
    final bottomRight = visibleRect.bottomRight.toVector2();
    final bottomLeft = visibleRect.bottomLeft.toVector2();

    return [
      Wall(topLeft, topRight),
      Wall(topRight, bottomRight),
      Wall(bottomLeft, bottomRight),
      Wall(topLeft, bottomLeft),
    ];
  }
}

class Ball extends BodyComponent with TapCallbacks {
  Ball({Vector2? initialPosition})
      : super(
          fixtureDefs: [
            FixtureDef(
              CircleShape()..radius = 5,
              restitution: 0.8,
              friction: 0.4,
            ),
          ],
          bodyDef: BodyDef(
            angularDamping: 0.8,
            position: initialPosition ?? Vector2.zero(),
            type: BodyType.dynamic,
          ),
        );

  @override
  void onTapDown(_) {
    body.applyLinearImpulse(Vector2.random() * 5000);
  }
}

class Wall extends BodyComponent {
  final Vector2 _start;
  final Vector2 _end;

  Wall(this._start, this._end);

  @override
  Body createBody() {
    final shape = EdgeShape()..set(_start, _end);
    final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(shape, friction: 0.3);
    final bodyDef = BodyDef(
      position: Vector2.zero(),
    );

    return world.createBody(bodyDef)..createFixture(fixtureDef);
  }
}

class DominoBrick extends BodyComponent {
  final Vector2 _position;

  DominoBrick(this._position);

  @override
  Body createBody() {
    final shape = PolygonShape()..setAsBoxXY(0.125, 2.0);
    final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(
      shape,
      density: 25.0,
      restitution: 0.4,
      friction: 0.5,
    );

    final bodyDef = BodyDef(type: BodyType.dynamic, position: _position);
    return world.createBody(bodyDef)..createFixture(fixtureDef);
  }
}


References:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79287495/how-can-i-draw-a-rectangle-in-flame-forge2d
https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/packages/flame_forge2d/example/lib/main.dart
https://examples.flame-engine.org/#/flame_forge2d_Domino_example


Have you considered adding a tiny random perturbation to the objects' initial states or in response to each collision to mimic some real-world messiness?

I've thought about it, but I'm not very familiar with collision implementation, and I'm not sure where to write what. I'll try a bit. On the other hand, I also thought that adjusting something like friction coefficients might work fine automatically, but it doesn't seem to be possible just through settings, right?

Unfortunately friction won't add an asymmetry where one isn't already present. You need some tiny shift to make the ball want to tip left more than right, or right more than left. A tiny bit of sideways velocity or angular velocity, or a shift just past the support footprint of the beam would be needed.
